# Javascript files not loading in HTML page

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js

I have a folder structure like this:

[image: Folder Structure]

I have referenced data.js and app.js like this:

[image: js file reference]

but my HTML page does not display my data. I tried using the full file path as well but that does not seem to work either. I tried this ../../UFOs/static/js/data.js as well from another question

I think the error might be in my app.js file. I used console.log on internet explorer and it pointed to a syntax error on the highlighted line:

[image: app.js]

app.js

```
// import the data from data.js
const tableData = data;

// Reference the HTML table using d3
var tbody = d3.select("tbody");
function buildTable(data) {
  data.forEach((dataRow) => {
    let row = tbody.append("tr");
    Object.values(dataRow).forEach((val) => {
      let cell = row.append("td");
      cell.text(val);
      }
    );
  });


function handleClick() {
    // Grab the datetime value from the filter
    let date = d3.select("#datetime").property("value");
    let filteredData = tableData;
  
     // Check to see if a date was entered and filter the
    // data using that date.
    if (date) {
      // Apply `filter` to the table data to only keep the
      // rows where the `datetime` value matches the filter value
      filteredData = filteredData.filter(row => row.datetime === date);
    };
  
     // Rebuild the table using the filtered data
    // @NOTE: If no date was entered, then filteredData will
    // just be the original tableData.
    buildTable(filteredData);
  };
// Attach an event to listen for the form button
d3.selectAll("#filter-btn").on("click", handleClick);

// Build the table when the page loads
buildTable(tableData);
```

data.js

```
var data = [
  {
    datetime: "1/1/2010",
    city: "benton",
    state: "ar",
    country: "us",
    shape: "circle",
    durationMinutes: "5 mins.",
    comments: "4 bright green circles high in the sky going in circles then one bright green light at my front door."
  },
  {
    datetime: "1/1/2010",
    city: "bonita",
    state: "ca",
    country: "us",
    shape: "light",
    durationMinutes: "13 minutes",
    comments: "Three bright red lights witnessed floating stationary over San Diego New Years Day 2010"
  }
  ];
```

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>UFO Finder</title>
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css"
      integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="static/css/style.css">
    
</head>
<body class="bg-dark">
    <div class="wrapper">
        <nav class="navbar navbar-dark bg-dark navbar-expand-lg">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html">UFO Sightings</a>
        </nav>
        <div class="jumbotron">
            <h1 class="display-4">The Truth Is Out There</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <h3>UFO Sightings: Fact or Fancy? <small>Ufologists Weigh In</small></h3>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-8">
                   
                        
                        <p>Some text</p>

                </div>
                <div class="container-fluid">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-3">
                            <form class="bg-dark">
                                <p>Filter Search</p>
                                <ul class="list-group bg-dark">
                                    <li class="list-group-item bg-dark">
                                        <label for="date">Enter Date</label>
                                        <input type="text" placeholder="1/10/2010" id="datetime"/>
                                    </li>
                                    <li class="list-group-item bg-dark">
                                        <button id="filter-btn" type="button" class="btn btn-dark" >Filter Table</button>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                            </form>

                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-9">
                            <table class="table table-striped">
                                <thead>
                                    <tr>
                                        <th>Date</th>
                                        <th>City</th>
                                        <th>State</th>
                                        <th>Country</th>
                                        <th>Shape</th>
                                        <th>Duration</th>
                                        <th>Comments</th>
                                    </tr>
                                </thead>
                            </table>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    
    
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/4.11.0/d3.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./static/js/data.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./static/js/app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your path is relative to your index file, which is already in the static folder. Try just `./js/data.js` and `./js/app.js`.

Comment: in the browser developer tools console can you see the javascript file is being  loaded without error? or is there a 404 error?

Comment: @JaromandaX There is no 404 error in the console

Comment: @Steve I tried "./js/data.js" and the data still does not load. I just check the console and I have file not found error using "./js/data.js"

Comment: so, the browser thinks it's loading the JS? regardless of which path you try?

Comment: I get file not found with these:
1) ../../UFOs/static/js/data.js
2) ../static/js/data.js  These 1) static/js/data.js
2) ./static/js/data.js show no errors

Comment: what about `js/data.js`

Comment: @JaromandaX no dice

Comment: `js/data.js` should work. did you try putting `console.log` in your `app.js` or `data.js` to check

Comment: We'd need more information from you before this can be answered with any amount of confidence. You've defined a function called `buildTable()`, but did you actually invoke it? Can you show us where/how you've invoked it? Can we see how `tbody` was defined? We basically need to see more of data.js and app.js.

Comment: "...on internet explorer and it pointed to a syntax error". This is a red herring. Your code won't work in IE 11 because you've used ES2015 syntax. It's a completely separate issue. I'd strongly advise not using IE 11 to test this while debugging this issue. If you really need it to work in IE 11 (I'd avoid it if at all possible...), I'd suggest getting everything working in Chrome/Firefox and porting the code to ES5 afterwords.

Comment: @HPierce I just added code for app.js and data.js

Comment: @aolayeye - in one of your scenarios where you DON'T get a 404 Error (file not found) on data.js, try typing `data` into the console. Does it return anything or does it tell you `data is not defined`? Also, as Stacks Queue suggests, try adding `console.log('app loaded');` and `console.log('data loaded');` to the end of app.js and data.js respectively and see if either or both lines display in the console.

Comment: @Daveh0 I get data loaded and app loaded

Comment: @Daveh0 When I type data in the console, I get: " (111) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}"

Comment: assuming `data` has 111 items, it looks like the `data` IS loading. Now add `console.log('row appended')` after `let row = tbody.append("tr");` and `console.log('cell appended')` after `let cell = row.append("td");`.

Comment: @Daveh0 I get row appended and cell appended multiple times. If I counted, I'm certain it will be 111 times

Comment: Is it printing 7 `cell appended` for each `row appended`? please copy and paste the HTML output in the inspector

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/234390/discussion-between-aolayeye-and-daveh0).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add `<tbody></tbody>` after `</thead>` in your HTML.

While a `<tbody>` is not required under the HTML5 spec, your function attempts to append the new rows to that element, so without it, they cannot be displayed, which is the exact problem you are experiencing.

Alternatively, you could have modified your function to append the rows to the table itself.

```
const dataTable = d3.select('table');
function buildTable(data) {
  data.forEach((dataRow) => {
    let row = dataTable.append("tr");
    Object.values(dataRow).forEach((val) => {
      let cell = row.append("td");
      cell.text(val);
    });
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have syntax errors in app.js, try the below code. buildTable function doesn't have closing brackets.

```js
     
    // import the data from data.js
    const tableData = data;
    
    // Reference the HTML table using d3
    var tbody = d3.select("tbody");
    function buildTable(data) {
      data.forEach((dataRow) => {
        let row = tbody.append("tr");
        Object.values(dataRow).forEach((val) => {
          let cell = row.append("td");
          cell.text(val);
          });
      });
    }
    function handleClick() {
        // Grab the datetime value from the filter
        let date = d3.select("#datetime").property("value");
        let filteredData = tableData;
      
         // Check to see if a date was entered and filter the
        // data using that date.
        if (date) {
          // Apply `filter` to the table data to only keep the
          // rows where the `datetime` value matches the filter value
          filteredData = filteredData.filter(row => row.datetime === date);
        }
      
         // Rebuild the table using the filtered data
        // @NOTE: If no date was entered, then filteredData will
        // just be the original tableData.
        buildTable(filteredData);
      }
    // Attach an event to listen for the form button
    d3.selectAll("#filter-btn").on("click", handleClick);
    
    // Build the table when the page loads
    buildTable(tableData);
```

Comment: apologies @dev , I think I missed the last 2 bits of code when edited the question. I just updated the part after the buildTable function

Comment: @aolayeye I have updated the code, try again

Comment: the data is still not displaying

Comment: Do you see any syntax errors or errors on console?